# Treat child as field of parent in elastic search query

Tags: parent-child, elasticsearch

I am reading the docs for elasticsearch and this [page][1] talks about mapping a child to a parent type using `_parent`.

If I have childs called `email` attached to parents called `account`:

Fields in each type:

```
account (http://localhost:9200/myapp/account/1)
========
id
name
some_other_info
state

email (http://localhost:9200/myapp/email/1?parent=1)
========
id
email
```

- How can I search on the `name` field of `account` and the `email` field of `email` provided that the `state` of `account` is `active`?
- Is there a way to get all the children (of a certain type or of any type) a parent owns?
- When indexing a child document, is it possible to to pass the parent as an object property in the JSON data as opposed to it being part of the query string?

---

After trying imotov's suggestion, I came up with this query:

This is executed on `http://localhost:9200/myapp/account/_search`

```
{
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "must": [
        {
          "prefix": {
            "name": "a"
          }
        },
        {
          "term": {
            "statuses": "active"
          }
        }
      ],
      "should": [
        {
          "has_child": {
            "type": "emailaddress",
            "query": {
              "prefix": {
                "email": "a"
              }
            }
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

The problem is that the above does not give me any accounts where the email matches.

The effect I want is essentially this:

- There is one search box
- Users start typing and the search box autocompletes.
- The user's query is checked against the name of the `account` or any of the `emailaddress` type.
- If `accounts` were matched, just return them. If `emailaddress` were match, return its parent account.
- Limit to a maximum of x (say 10) accounts for each search.

So, I basically need to be able to `OR` the search between 2 types and return the parent type of matches.

---

Test data:

```
curl -XPUT http://localhost:9200/test/account/1 -d '{
    "name": "John Smith",
    "statuses": "active"
}'

curl -XPUT http://localhost:9200/test/account/2 -d '{
    "name": "Peter Smith",
    "statuses": "active"
}'

curl -XPUT http://localhost:9200/test/account/3 -d '{
    "name": "Andy Smith",
    "statuses": "active"
}'

//Set up mapping for parent/child relationship

curl -XPUT 'http://localhost:9200/test/email/_mapping' -d '{
    "emails" : {
        "_parent" : {"type" : "account"}
    }
}'

curl -XPUT http://localhost:9200/test/email/1?parent=1 -d '{
    "email": "john@smith.com"
}'

curl -XPUT http://localhost:9200/test/email/2?parent=1 -d '{
    "email": "admin@mycompany.com"
}'

curl -XPUT http://localhost:9200/test/email/3?parent=1 -d '{
    "email": "abcd@efg.com"
}'

curl -XPUT http://localhost:9200/test/email/4?parent=2 -d '{
    "email": "peter@peter.com"
}'

curl -XPUT http://localhost:9200/test/email/5?parent=3 -d '{
    "email": "andy@yahoo.com"
}'

curl -XPUT http://localhost:9200/test/email/6?parent=3 -d '{
    "email": "support@mycompany.com"
}'
```

---

imotov's solution worked for me. Another solution I have found is to query `account`s for `status = active`, then run a `bool` filter on the result and use `has_child` on the child type and `prefix` on `name` inside the `bool` filter.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

An important difference between elasticsearch and relational databases is that elasticsearch  cannot perform joins. In elasticsearch you are always searching a single index or union of indices. But in case of parent/child relationship, it's possible to limit results in the parent index using a query on the child index. For example, you can execute this query on the `account` type.

```
{
    "bool": {
        "must": [
            { 
                "text" : { "name": "foo" } 
            }, { 
                "term" : { "state": "active" } 
            }, {
                "has_child": {
                    "type": "email",
                    "query": {
                        "text": {"email": "bar" }
                    }
                }
            }
        ]
    }
}
```

This query will return you the parent document only (no child documents will be returned). You can use the parent id returned by this query to find all children of this parent using the field `_parent`, which is stored and indexed by default.

```
{
    "term" : { "_parent": "1" } 
}
```

Or you can limit your results only to the children that contain the word `bar` in the field `email`:

```
{
    "bool": {
        "must": [
            { 
                "term" : { "_parent": "1" } 
            }, { 
                "text" : { "email": "bar" } 
            }
        ]
    }
}
```

I don't think it's possible to specify parent in the json unless you are using [_bulk indexing](http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/reference/api/bulk.html).

This is how email lookup can be implemented using test data provided in the question:

```
#!/bin/sh
curl -XDELETE 'http://localhost:9200/test' && echo 
curl -XPOST 'http://localhost:9200/test' -d '{
    "settings" : {
        "number_of_shards" : 1,
        "number_of_replicas" : 0
    },
    "mappings" : {
      "account" : {
        "_source" : { "enabled" : true },
        "properties" : {
          "name": { "type": "string", "analyzer": "standard" },
          "statuses": { "type": "string",  "index": "not_analyzed" }
        }
      },
      "email" : {
        "_parent" : {
          "type" : "account"
        },
        "properties" : {
          "email": { "type": "string",  "analyzer": "standard" }
        }
      }
    }
}' && echo

curl -XPUT 'http://localhost:9200/test/account/1' -d '{
    "name": "John Smith",
    "statuses": "active"
}'

curl -XPUT 'http://localhost:9200/test/account/2' -d '{
    "name": "Peter Smith",
    "statuses": "active"
}'

curl -XPUT 'http://localhost:9200/test/account/3' -d '{
    "name": "Andy Smith",
    "statuses": "active"
}'

//Set up mapping for parent/child relationship

curl -XPUT 'http://localhost:9200/test/email/1?parent=1' -d '{
    "email": "john@smith.com"
}'

curl -XPUT 'http://localhost:9200/test/email/2?parent=1' -d '{
    "email": "admin@mycompany.com"
}'

curl -XPUT 'http://localhost:9200/test/email/3?parent=1' -d '{
    "email": "abcd@efg.com"
}'

curl -XPUT 'http://localhost:9200/test/email/4?parent=2' -d '{
    "email": "peter@peter.com"
}'

curl -XPUT 'http://localhost:9200/test/email/5?parent=3' -d '{
    "email": "andy@yahoo.com"
}'

curl -XPUT 'http://localhost:9200/test/email/6?parent=3' -d '{
    "email": "support@mycompany.com"
}'

curl -XPOST 'http://localhost:9200/test/_refresh'
echo
curl 'http://localhost:9200/test/account/_search' -d '{
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "must": [
        {
          "term": {
            "statuses": "active"
          }
        }
      ],
      "should": [
        {
          "prefix": {
            "name": "a"
          }
        },
        {
          "has_child": {
            "type": "email",
            "query": {
              "prefix": {
                "email": "a"
              }
            }
          }
        }
      ],
      "minimum_number_should_match" : 1
    }
  }
}' && echo
```

Comment: Thanks for your help! That got me started, but I feel that I have not communicated my question clearly. I have edited my question with further details.

Comment: From your description, it sounds like the first prefix query should be moved from the "must" clause to the "should" clause, because you want only active account AND either account match or email match. If this suggestion doesn't work, could you post a full repro with mapping and some test data?

Comment: I tried your suggestion, but for some reason it seems to just return all accounts, even ones that should not match. I have posted some test data with the mapping :)

Comment: Yes, that makes sense. I forgot about setting minimum_number_should_match in the query. I have added a working example to my answer.