# Returning a custom field where value depends on the query in elasticsearch

Tags: field, elasticsearch

I have some data like so in elasticsearch:

```
account (http://localhost:9200/myapp/account/1)
========
name
state
groups //groups is an array containing objects like so {id: 1, starred: true}
       //the id is the id of the group type

email (http://localhost:9200/myapp/email/1?parent=1)
========
email
primary //just a boolean to denote whether this email is primary or not

group
========
name
description
```

`email`s are children of `account`.

Based on [imotov's excellent answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11806584/treat-child-as-field-of-parent-in-elastic-search-query/11819361#11819361), I am able to run a search on `account.name` and `email.email` and return ALL `account`s where the searched prefix matches the above 2 fields:

```
{
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "must": [
        {
          "term": {
            "statuses": "active"
          }
        }
      ],
      "should": [
        {
          "prefix": {
            "name": "a"
          }
        },
        {
          "has_child": {
            "type": "email",
            "query": {
              "prefix": {
                "email": "a"
              }
            }
          }
        }
      ],
      "minimum_number_should_match" : 1
    }
  }
}
```

What I would like to do now is to return 2 custom fields for each result:

- For each result return a field called `email`, if the search was matched on the `email` type (which is a child of `account`), return that email, otherwise return the `primary` email linked to the account, if none, `null` can be returned.
- For each result return a field called `group`. The value of the field should contain the name of the starred `group` whose id is stored in the `groups` array. Essentially: Find `group.id` where `group.starred` is true in each `account.groups`, then return the matching `group.name` from the `group` type base on the id we found.

I have been looking at [script fields](http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/reference/api/search/script-fields.html), but I am not sure if it is able to return fields for each hit. I am also not sure if the above is actually accomplishable in ES.

Could someone provide some pointers as to whether this is possible and how to get started?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Currently, there is simply no way to get to access the data in a `has_child` or `nested` clause.

The only solution is to get some data, make some decisions on the client and then get more data.

Here's what I did to achieve it:

- Run the query above and get back the data.
- To deal with showing the match emails or the primary email (run on the email type):

  ```
  {"query":
      {"bool":{
         "should":{
          {
             "prefix":{
                "email" : "the query"
             }
          },
          {
             "terms":{
                "_parent" : ["list", "of", "account", "ids"]
            }
         }
        }
      }
    }
  }
  ```

Base on the above query, we can get any email addresses that were matched by the search term. Remember to set the fields in the above query to include `_parent`.

We can then use `array_diff()` or a similiar function in languages other than PHP to diff the parent ids from above and and original query. This should then give us a list of accounts where no email was matched. Simply then send another request to get the primary emails for those accounts.

For the groups, send a query to type `account` and:

- Constrain `_id` to the list of account ids.
- Constrain `group.starred` to `true`.

This should get you a list of starred groups. To get more information (name etc), send a query to type `group` and:

- Constrain `_id` to the group ids above.

Finally, do some client side processing to put it together so that it is easier for the next part of your program to use.